# Returning value from an observable operation in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, observable, synchronous

Am working in Angular and the problem seems to be: When I subscribe to the observable in my component, I can console.log() the data successfully, but I cannot assign the data to any afore declared variables and view it in the view template. This is the code: I understand that logging in the console is a synchronous process while the observable subscription in itself is asynchronous, but outputting a value from an asynchronous operation in the view template seems to be the problem. I have seen quite a number of solutions on stack overflow but it does not resolve the problem since it doesn't address this kind of problem. 
**This is a sample of the code**

```js
  //The getData function returns an obsverbale
  favoriteShirt;
  
  const gtc = this;
  gtc.getData().subscribe({
          next: (data) => { 
            console.log(data.favShirtFromStore) // this returns an objects with the shirts (this is a sync op)
            gtc.favoriteShirt = data.favShirtFromStore; //this returns undefined <= where the problem is
           },
           error:(err)=>{console.log(`There was an error ${err}`)},
           complete:()=>{console.log("Completed...")}
        });;
```

Comment: remove the return in "return gtc.favoriteShirt = data.favShirtFromStore;"

Comment: Yeah, thanks but even that still renders the value undefined.

Comment: I can't reproduce this... I've created a stackblitz and it logs it fine. Please feel free to fork it with a reproduction https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymzw51?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: How do you display the value in the template? Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: Using the {{value}}, however, it outputs nothing, however, the console.log outputs the value

Comment: Have you tried the async pipe ? you can use interpolation with async pipe {{ dataObservable | async }}. Can you post the HTML ?

Comment: Can you add the HTML to your question as well please?

Comment: @user184994 solution solved the issue. Thanks a lot to you all.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use it like this:

```
gtc.getData().subscribe(res => { 
    //whatever you want to do with res 
});
```

here `res` is returned data from your function and you can use it the way you want, such as assign it to another variable and so on ...